# How to toggle between two buttons in React and chnange the NAvlink path based on button clicked

Tags: reactjs, routes, toggle

I am trying to toggle between two images in react and trying to change the Navlink route based on the path enter image description here

```
<button className="lessonTypeButton">
  <img
    src={singleLessonsType}
    alt="singleLessonsType"
    className="packageOne"
    onClick={lessonSelected}
  />
</button>

<br />
<br />
<br />

<button className="lessonTypeButton">
  <img
    src={packageLessons}
    alt="packageLessons"
    className="packageTwo"
    onClick={lessonSelected}
  />
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have `href` property to have routes that in URL,

```
<button className="lessonTypeButton">
    <img
      src={packageLessons}
      alt="packageLessons"
      className="packageTwo"
      onClick={lessonSelected}
      href={/packageLessons}
    />
</button>
<button className="lessonTypeButton">
    <img
      src={singleLessonsType}
      alt="singleLessonsType"
      className="packageOne"
      onClick={lessonSelected}
      href={/singleLessonsType}
    />
</button>
```

or use hooks,

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
```

then use it in function,

```
let history = useHistory();

function lessonSelected = ()=>{
    history.push("/singleLessonsType");
}
```

or simply call onclick event directly,

```
<button className="lessonTypeButton">
    <img
      src={packageLessons}
      alt="packageLessons"
      className="packageTwo"
      onClick={history.push("/packageLessons");}
    />
</button>
<button className="lessonTypeButton">
    <img
      src={singleLessonsType}
      alt="singleLessonsType"
      className="packageOne"
      onClick={history.push("/singleLessonsType");}
    />
</button>
```